# How to compile multiple CSS files into two CSS files output based on each one required in different layout using Laravel Mix

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-mix

I have two CSS files app.css(RTL CSS) and en-app.css(LTR CSS) I want to compile them using Laravel Mix into two files, How I can (I don't want to paste them directly in Public/CSS directory Instead I want to use advantages of Mix)

Comment: You need to ad the code to your question to get answers. But I would say, take a look at `webpack.mix.js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be quite straightforward. Usually you should have something like  `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css');` in you mix file. As you can see you can stack multiple calls to the mix function. So you will need to make a separate call to `.scss` `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'js').sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'css').sass('resources/sass/en-app.scss', 'css');`

After running the compiler you should see the two files in the `./public/css/`  folder.

Note: If you are using plain CSS you will need to replace `.scss` with `.css` function in the mix file.